# ¿Cómo enviar URL a una condición de consulta sin barra?

Tags: php

Al insertar un post, mi sistema me registra automáticamente una url según el titulo de la noticia ejemplo: `dominio.com/blog/una-noticia-nueva/`

Aveces al editar los datos al igual que la `URL`, me se olvidar de agregarle la barra invertida dejando de la siguiente forma `dominio.com/blog/una-noticia-nueva`

Es un problema a la hora de reflejar datos,  ya que el `.htaccess` toda las `URL` la direcciona con una barra invertida al final.

Por ejemplo yo tengo lo siguientes registro:

```
id    url
1     una-noticia-nueva/
2     un-post-nuevo
```

A la hora de obtener la URL `una-noticia-nueva/` por el siguiente código

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $obtenerurl = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Como le envió esa URL a la consulta `WHERE url=?` de la siguiente manera: `una-noticia-nueva` sin la barra al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un explode de la variable y llevarte el primer elemento del resultado, funcionará tanto con barra final como sin ella.

```
$url = "una-noticia-nueva/";
$url_procesada = explode("/",$url);
$url = $url_procesada[0];
```

O aun más sencillo, reemplazar directamente el carácter:

```
$url = str_replace("/","",$url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como quieres eliminar la barra si se encuentra al final de la URI, puedes **comprobar si es el carácter en la última posición y** de ser así, **obtener el string sin este último carácter**.

> Ejemplo

Voy a eliminar un signo de exclamación al final de la cadena:

```
<?php

$str = "hola mundo!";
$lastCharPosition = strlen($str) - 1;
if ($str[$lastCharPosition] === "!") {
    $str = substr($str, 0, $lastCharPosition);
}
echo($str);
```

> Resultado:

```
hola mundo
```